# how to list files in a directory without redirecting to index.php file?

Tags: php, curl

i am writing a simple script to list all the files of an external sites directory. i am using curl for this. the code i have written is below

```
$url="http://externalsite.com/directory/";
```

$ch = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);       

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

but when i execute the above code it is showing the contents of the index.php file which is in the directory. how to list all the files in the directory without redirecting it to index.php file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is not controlled by the client, it is up to the server to decide what will be served. For example, depending on the server configuration, the default file that will be served by apache is index.php, index.html, or the contents of the directory if none of the above is present there and the Indexes option is not disabled.